# Solution of the DE $y'=f(x)$ where $f(x)=I_{[0, 1]}(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Solution of the DE $y'=f(x)$ where $f(x)=I_{[0, 1]}(x)$, where $x \in [0, 2]$. Here $I$ denotes the indicator function.

Ans: $y(x)=x+C_{1}$ in $[0, 1]$ and $y(x)=c_{2}$ in $(1, 2]$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct so far, but it is not complete. You need to ensure continuity in $x=1$, that is, $c_2=1+c_1$.

As there is no $C^1$ function solving the equation in the strict sense, one can demand that at least the integral form 
$$
y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^x f(s)\,ds
$$
is satisfied, which gives a continuous solution. Note that in the case of a continuous right side, the differential formulation $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ and integral form $y(x)=y(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf(s,y(s))ds$ of the ODE are equivalent.

Comment: but given that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1$

Comment: @420 the derivative can be discontinuous

Comment: can we say that it has no solution if we consider it as IVP?

Comment: An IVP needs a pair $x_0,y_0$ with $y(x_0)=y_0$ which you haven't gave us.

Comment: $y(x)=y_0+\min(x,1)$ is a perfectly valid solution, I do not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: for any initial condition, as $f(x)$ is discontinuous there is question of existence of solution by Picard theorem.

Comment: Yes, you need a more general solution concept. Here it is sufficient to say "differentiable where $f$ is continuous, and as smooth as possible at the jumps of $f$." This is only for this simple integration problem. If the discontinuity depends on $y$, you need something like Filippov, or more specifically, sliding mode solutions.